# Stop any current audio on play

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio

I would like to have any previously played audio to be stopped before playing a new audio clip over the previous. This is to prevent double clips on elements which will play the audio file multiple times.

I tried to pause and set the current time to 0 but neither are working. What is the correct way to do this?

```
        $(".playAudio").on('click touchstart', function () {
            var audio = document.createElement('audio');
            audio.setAttribute('src', $(this).attr('data-audio'));
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.play();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pause the `audio` clip if it exists.

The code below should work.

```
let audio;

$(".playAudio").on('click touchstart', function () {

   if(audio){
     audio.pause();
   }

   audio = document.createElement('audio');
   audio.setAttribute('src', $(this).attr('data-audio'));
   audio.currentTime = 0;
   audio.play();
});
```

Comment: The variable definition `let audio;` should be outside of the function. Currently it's being created at the start end discarded at the end of the function.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald ikkuh is correct. If you update the answer I'll mark it as correct.